# click on div with javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how can i do something with javascript to click on div like

i have a div with display none like this

```
<div style="display:none;" id="button">Hello World</div>
```

when that div changed display to block then with javascript must click on that div ?

i have tried this but i want to make it like i said above

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button').trigger('click');
});

</script >
```

Comment: _when that div changed display to block_ how this display change?

Comment: it's a click able div, so what i am trying ti do is when some script sees that display div changed to block hen it must click on it

Comment: just use .click() but anyway your question is not making much sense,

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button').trigger('focusin');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','#button',function() {
        // your code here, example
        alert('divClick');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click on to the button use [$.click](https://api.jquery.com/click/). 
This function is not only a handler. Please read the docs above.

```
$("#button").click();
```